# 6 to 0 count down timer

Tags: flipflop, counter, 7segmentdisplay, synchronous, ripple-counter

I'm making a 60 second timer.  I already made the 1st digit in my previous question. I want it to start at 6 not 0, basically 6,5,4,3,2,1,0. I made the flipflop state table and followed the similar process I used in the first digit.

But when simulating it, it starts at 0,7,6.... I want it to start at 6.  How can I do this?

Below are the table and schematic I made:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When facing this question (and exactly how it is faced depends on whether you are building something physically with genuine parts or using a simulator), I simply use the power-up reset state as the initial state and select either the \$Q\$ or \$\overline{Q}\$ output, as appropriate.

*(In some physical reality cases, you don't know the power-up state. In such cases, they will usually provide a **CLR** and/or **SET** pin. I'd attach a power-on reset circuit so that the FFs are held in either **CLR** or **SET** state while the power supply becomes stable, releasing that line only after the supply is known-stable.)*

So, in this case, the JK FF powers up with \$Q=0\$ and \$\overline{Q}=1\$. Since you want the initial state to be \$6\$ this just means that you set things up so that your ***actual*** output is taken as \$\overline{Q_2}\:\overline{Q_1}\:Q_0\$.

So the states will be \$0\$, \$3\$, \$2\$, \$5\$, \$4\$, \$7\$, and \$6\$. And take \$\overline{Q_2}\$, \$\overline{Q_1}\$, and \$Q_0\$ as the counter output.

You have proven yourself being able to produce the rest, I believe.

Comment: I got it connected with the first circuit where it relies on an output, so that the clk of the 2nd circuit (this circuit) is an output that is in the 1st circuit.

Comment: @Noobielectrix You get things quickly and you are going to be a powerhouse in this area! Best wishes!